# TypeError: _lodash2.default.get is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs

im getting this error after I used npm install --save bctypt
TypeError: _lodash2.default.get is not a function
Before I installed bcrypt, everything worked

my code is:

user.js

```
import _ from 'lodash'


    create(cb){

        const model = this.model;
        const db = this.app.db;
        const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(model.password, saltRounds);
        model.password = hashPassword;

        this.validate((errors) => {

        });
```

the code with the error (router.js):
            const body = _.get(req, 'body');

```
        // Create new users
        app.post('/api/users', (req, res, next) => {

            const body = _.get(req, 'body');
            console.log("data from fronted:", body);

            const user = new User(app);

            user.initWithObject(body);

            user.initWithObject(body).create((err, newUser) => {

                console.log("New user created with error & callback", err, newUser);

                if(err){

                    return res.status(503).json({
                        error: {message: err}
                    });

                }

                return res.status(200).json(newUser);

            });

        });
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are using version of lodash not less than 3.7.0 - where _.get was introduced